# Error running .NET framework apps in VS on Win11

Tags: asp.net, .net, windows, visual-studio, windows-11

**Error**: "process with an Id of xxxx is not running"

versions and debugging steps below - (I essentially tried various reinstallations of every related program, prior to the full reinstallations I also attempted a dozen or so types of cache clears and configuration changes within Visual Studio. It can be replicated however with fresh installations)

**OS** Name: Microsoft Windows 11 Pro
Version 10.0.22621 Build 22621
(tried on both old and fresh installation of the above LTS version, plus 2 additional attempts prior versions that I was updating over the past couple weeks)

**VS** 2022 (LTS)
Tried both community (17.9.2) and pro versions
(uninstalled and reinstalled multiple times, deleting all temp/cache folders with each attempt)

**IIS express** that installs default on VS version above
also attempted uninstalling and reinstalling using IIS express 10.0 from site downloaded yesterday 3/11/2024 with the following build number: 3.14.0.572...
Also attempted disabling IIS completely in windows, restart, re-enable, and successful retest of .NET core app

**.NET Framework** v4.8.1
Newly installed GIT repo fails with the above error
Created a new project, using default settings on a new MVC template, error can be replicated.

**.NET core** all new and old applications work just fine - tried LTS and 1 older version on each .NET core 6 and 7

The only thing I could think of is that:
a: This specific set-up doesn't work on windows 11 (I tried on a windows 10 PC and it works fine) - but I see no other documentation online of other people having the same issue
b: I'm not understanding *something*

I will create a MS support ticket if this is a genuine version compatibility issue - but I wanted to post this publicly to see if there are others replicating/experiencing the same issue first.

Ideal state is to open a .NET Framework webpage in IIS express.

Edit:
Adding photo of execution on a fresh MVC repo in VS admin mode
[image: Error in admin mode]
[image: vs installation (2)]
[image: vs installation]

Comment: Do you have a sample repro that does not work, and a reproduceable example? Without a sample that reproduces your issue, we really can't help you.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal
Are you unable to reproduce it with the steps I noted? It doesn't work for me for any repo, newly created projects are also not connecting. (referenced using a blank MVC VS base project template as the repo) - must have the .NET framework templates installed to VS to create that.

Comment: so, steps are create a new MVC project, but as .net framework and NOT as .net core. Yes, that works just fine for me, see my post below.

Comment: There isn't much to ask here, as like you found out no one else can easily reproduce this. Escalate to your company's IT support and let them diagnose this issue for you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able without issues able to create a new MVC project, and one that is .net framework. I thus assume this project type:

[image]

After selecting above, then I get this:

[image]

[image]

And then I get this:

[image]

And then hitting F5 to build + run, I get this:

[image]

As noted, if the basic create and run of a new project was broken, then millions of users of Visual Studio would be having your problem, and clearly they don't.

As noted, if you trying to create a webforms project, then you have to for vs2022 install the additional workflows, as they are not installed by default.

I'm on windows 11, vs2022, v17.9.2

## Edit: Make sure additional workflows are installed

So, to make sure ISS is installed, and other bits and parts, then select these work flows (menu->Get tools and features).

Hence these:

[image]

So, now in your new created project, then project->"project name" properties.

And on the web tab, check these settings:

[image]

So, force the bit ness  to x64 bit version.

And also click on the Create Virtual Directory button.

So, right now, this looks like IIS is not installed, or you want to force the project to x64 bits, and also try clicking on the virtual directory button.

Comment: I see, on this exact workflow I can replicate the error. I'm on a fresh installation of win 11 - however it is security managed by my company so perhaps there's a setting on my machine that I cannot see that's effecting this. Thanks for reviewing this, I will attempt on a new machine shortly and update the post accordingly

Comment: Try when launching VS you use "run as administrator" So, tap windows key, type in visual studio, and then in the hit list, right click and choose run as administrator. Remember, the default source folder is under your user name, sources and then repo's.  So, often their are rights attached to a given folder. I not launched VS without "run as administrator" in 10 years.......

Comment: I did try admin mode a number of times throughout debugging. But since I didn't keep track of which versions I tried it with I uploaded a screenshot of the error in admin mode

Comment: See my edit  -- what you have so far suggests that IIS is not setup, or it has some issue. So, in my edit, make sure you select and install all of the workflows - not just the one I marked with a "arrow" (so, select all the bits and parts I have selected). And try the create virtual directory, and try forcing the web server to run as x64 bits.

Comment: Closing this item, as the problem seems machine specific.
The most likely cause was a change in company run security software versions between windows 10 and windows 11. These software's directly modify settings in the OS and was causing IIS to behave abnormally in a very specific scenario. changing back to the w10 version of the security software on a new w10 machine resolved the issue, I don't anticipate this ticket helping too many users in the future.